# Open image from a link in HTML file, parsed from JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, image

So I have the text of an image source from the internet in my database. I took the text of the image source out and I am trying display the image in the HTML.This is what I have:

```
 var cover = JSON.stringify(json);
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.id = "picture";
  image.src = cover;
  var display = document.getElementById("results");
  display.appendChild(image);
```

I get the null image icon to show up in my browser. Thanks! 
Javscript ONLY please

Comment: What does your json object look like?

Comment: Could you console.log(cover); ?

Comment: console.log comes out as this[{"cover":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/615C7P4pmdL._AA160_.jpg"},{"cover":"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61nwtHCYOqL._AA160_.jpg"}]

Comment: Try `image.src = cover[0].cover`

Comment: Thanks! I got it working by using image.src=json[0].cover